# How do I add two numbers in JavaScript "without using `+` or `-` operators"?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I know an alternative to using the `+` sign for addition is to do something like this:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
     if(b == 0)
         return sum;
     sum = a ^ b;
     carry = (a & b) << 1;
     return add(sum,carry);
}
```

But I have two problems:

- This is C++, not JavaScript. Is this supported in JavaScript?
- It's obvious the whole trick is in `^` `&` `<<`, but I don't know how to start looking for them in JavaScript, because **I don't know what they are called**.
  What should I be googling for even?

I tried to write this in JavaScript ... but seems I miss something

```
var getSum = function(a, b) {
  return (a ^ b, (a & b) << 1)
};
```

Comment: You're not providing any code or example of what you've tried.  You're essentially posting a Comp Sci homework assignment into stack overflow and asking us to solve it for you.  You even link to a question that already shows you a method.

Comment: No amount of questions on stack overflow will replace your own study.  To really understand the answer, you can't just ask us "how to" solve the problem.  You have to attempt to solve it yourself, and if you get stuck, provide the code _and the results_.  Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators and start learning about bitwise operations.  They're essentially the same in just about all languages.  Then come back and ask a specific question about the code you wrote when you get stuck.

Comment: well the algorithm you copied, you did not copy the recursion.... http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-two-numbers-without-using-arithmetic-operators/

Comment: `&` = bitwise AND, << = bitwise left shift - and what your getSum function is actually returning is just `(a & b) << 1` - the `a^b` part is not returned and has no effect - that's due to the way the  `,` operator works

Comment: @Microsmsm this has been downvoted because it seems pretty clear that you didn't make any effort in producing any try, nor reading a document about JS operators.

Comment: One way of doing this job in JS is `var add = (a,b) => b ? add(a^b,(a&b)<<1) : a;`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We will use [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) and will use [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

We use this method when we have a few low resources. [Read more about when to use this method!](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding)

```js
var getSum = function(a, b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return getSum(a ^ b, (a & b) << 1)
    }
};
```

ECMAScript 6 one-liner solution as suggested by @PatrickRoberts:

```js
const getSum = (a,b) => b ? getSum(a ^ b, (a & b) << 1) : a;
```

**Another solutions:**

2- Arrays technique [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

```js
const getSum = (a, b) => {
  const firstArr = new Array(a).fill(true);
  const secondArr = new Array(b).fill(true);
  return firstArr.concat(secondArr).length
}
```

3- workaround to [use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) plus sign [without writing it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode):

```js
const getSum = (a, b) => eval(''.concat(a).concat(String.fromCharCode(0x2B)).concat(b));
```

Comment: `const getSum = (a, b) => b == 0 ? a : getSum(a ^ b, (a & b) << 1);`

Comment: A very similar one-liner [had been suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455750/how-to-add-two-numbers-in-javascript-without-using-or-operators/41456431#comment70175130_41455750) by Redu.

Comment: point number 2 will fail in case we have negative numbers eg a = -1, b = 1, result should b 0

Answer (score 9):

Well ok i am answering to the question as clearly described in the header. No `+` and no `-` operations right..? Yet... not with bitwise but with pure math should be a valid answer i suppose.

```js
var x   = 1,
    y   = 2,
    sum = Math.log2(2**x * 2**y);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: The accepted answer may only handle 32 bit integers. But this one works for all numbers (with some floating point errors...).

Comment: Even with some problems with floating points, this is very original:) I like your solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
const add = (a, b) => new Function('a', 'b', `return ${a} ${String.fromCharCode(43)} ${b}`)(a, b);
```

Comment: Provide the explanation for your answer ?

Comment: Try and convince me your way of *having neither a `+` nor a `-` operator in the source code* is *without using `+` or `-` operators*.

Comment: Use eval should be more effective. `const add = eval(unescape('(a, b) => a %2b b'))`

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use arrays structures to perform a sum operation.

```
function getSum(a, b){
  return Array(a).concat(Array(b)).length / 100;
}
```

Each input is coerced to an array, for instance, an input of value 5 would be coerced to an array of 5 elements. After coercing both inputs, the arrays are joined into a single array. The length of the final array is returned, by dividing to **100** to deal with the sum of decimal values.

Now, let's try to be defensive about invalid input cases, such as `strings` or falsy values.

```
const DEFAULT_NUMBER_VALUE = 0;
const DEFAULT_PRECISION = 100;

function parseAddInput(input){
  if (!input) {
    return DEFAULT_NUMBER_VALUE;
  }
  
  if (typeof input === 'string'){
    input = parseInt(input);
  }
  
  const roundedNumber = Math.round(input * (10 * DEFAULT_PRECISION));
  
  return roundedNumber;
}

function getSum(a, b){
  return Array(
    parseAddInput(a)
  ).concat(
    Array(parseAddInput(b))
  ).length / 100;
}

function add(number1, number2){
  return getSum(number1, number2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can implement same using while loop. We have to shift the carry to left and add it to binary sum of numbers till there will no carry. (As we follows the practice in addition of decimals.)

```js
function getSum(a, b){
  while(b!=0){
    var carry = a&b;  //calculate if is there any carry we need to add
    a = a^b;   // a is used to hold the sum
    b = carry<<1;  //b is used to hold left shift carry
  }
  return a;
}

document.write(getSum(7, 5))
```

Comment: Instead of `a = a^b;`, could use `a ^= b;`